# Logistic Regression on multiple classes (Shouldn't it be only on binary?)

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, multiple-regression, categorical-data, predictive-models

I'm a bit confused with the usage of logistic regression for multi-class classification. My understanding is that a logistic regression is dichotomous (two possible classes), so in the example of the *Iris* sepal/petal there are 3 Species:

```
1. *setosa*, 
2. *versicolor* and 
3. *virginca*
```

If we run a logistic regression on the *Iris* dataset, how can it distinguish between the 3 species?

code example:

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train) 

predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

results in:

```
array(['versicolor', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
       'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
       'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor',
       'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'setosa',
       'virginica', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
       'virginica', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: See the documentation: “ In the multiclass case, the training algorithm uses the one-vs-rest (OvR) scheme if the ‘multi_class’ option is set to ‘ovr’, and uses the cross-entropy loss if the ‘multi_class’ option is set to ‘multinomial’.”

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression generalizes logistic regression to more than 2 outcomes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending my comment into an answer:

There are several natural extensions to handle multiple classes, and two are built into `scikit-learn`. Multinomial logistic regression is still logistic regression. And one-versus-rest classification is another common way to extend a binary classifier to multiple classes.

See the [scikit-learn `LogisticRegression` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) for how multi-class prediction is handled in the software you’re using.

> In the multiclass case, the training algorithm uses the one-vs-rest (OvR) scheme if the ‘multi_class’ option is set to ‘ovr’, and uses the cross-entropy loss if the ‘multi_class’ option is set to ‘multinomial’.